# ThreeJS Object Clone Properties are Undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, copy, clone

In ThreeJS (and typescript) I am creating an instance of a custom object which extends Object3D, then attempting to clone it. However, the field (one required for new object creation) gets an `undefined` value during the process. Here's the code:

```js
import {Object3D, Vector3} from "three";

export class CustomObject extends Object3D{

    // a single property
    prop: Vector3;

    // assigns property value during creation
    constructor(prop: Vector3) {
        super();
        this.prop = prop;
        console.log("Prop: ", this.prop);
    }
}

// creates an object
let co = new CustomObject(new Vector3(0, 1, 2));

// clones the object
let coc = co.clone();
console.log("Clone prop: ", coc.prop);
```

In the console, I see the following:

```
Prop:  Vector3 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 2}  <---- called during initial object creation.
Prop:  undefined                   <---- called during clone operation.
Clone Prop:  undefined             <---- called at the end.
```

Why is `prop` `undefined` after the first instance?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel a bit silly at this point but will post this as an answer for posterity:

Custom objects need custom clone methods:

```js
clone(){
    let clon = super.clone();
    clon.prop = this.prop;
    return clon
}
```